# Difference between newScheduledThreadPool(1) and newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()

Tags: java

I am wondering what is the difference between these two methods of Executors class? I have a web application where I'm checking some data every 100 ms so that's why I'm using this scheduler with scheduleWithFixedDelay method. I want to know which method should I use in this case (newScheduledThreadPool or  newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor)?
I also have one more question - in VisualVM where I monitor my Glassfish server I noticed that I have some threads in PARK state - for example:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for <3cb9965d> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is it possible that these threads are connected with scheduler because I don't have any idea what else would create them? These threads are never destroyed, so I am afraid that this could cause some troubles. Here is a screenshot (new Thread-35 will be created in 15minutes and so on...):

[image]

Comment: A thread pool is a pool/group of threads that have a pre-configured number of threads (to start with). This is useful if you have a work-intensive scenario where each thread in the pool might work for a longer time and you want the work to be done sooner, so you create a pool of threads. A single thread - as the name implies, is just one thread executing over and over again. Depending on the nature of work and the complexity of the task, you choose between a single or pool of threads.

Answer (score 8):

As [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()) states:

> Unlike the otherwise equivalent newScheduledThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads.

So when using `newScheduledThreadPool(1)`you will be able to add more threads later.

Comment: Yes, I read this before. So there is just difference in adding more threads later? What about this statement (from documentation fornewSingleThreadExecutor ): "(Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.)" - do this also apply for newScheduledThreadPool(1) or not?

Comment: Yes, it's also apply.

Comment: The pragmatic difference is that `newScheduledThreadPool(N)` with `N` > 1, will keep a number of threads in an idle state. The scheduled tasks can run in different threads, but they follow the `happen-before` model, which in this case basically means, that no two scheduled tasks will ever run in parallel (tasks scheduled for exactly the same execution time are enabled in first-in-first-out (FIFO) order of submission). If the current thread dies, a new one can be simply taken from the pool which may be faster. Executor will maintain the number of thread to be `N`.

Answer (score 6):

*newSingleThreadScheduledExecuto()* is wrapped by a delegate, as you can see in *Executors.java*:

```
public static ScheduledExecutorService newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() {
    return new DelegatedScheduledExecutorService(new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1));
}
```

Differences (from javadoc):

> if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.
>
> Unlike the otherwise equivalent {@code newScheduledThreadPool(1)} the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads.

reply to your comment:

> do this also apply for newScheduledThreadPool(1) or not?

no, you need to take care of thread failure yourself.

As for Unsafe.park(), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241335/waiting-at-sun-misc-unsafe-parknative-method).

Comment: OK, thank you. So for my case I think it's fine to use newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(). Is it possible that I have these PARK state threads (see screenshot above) because of using newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()? EDIT: I saw topic about Unsafe.park() already but I can't figure it out what is causing it, so I am wondering if someone knows if there were any problems connected with scheduler...

Comment: @user4341206 Sorry, I'm no sure. But it seems likely. Because the single thread will be kept in the thread pool even when idle.

Comment: When the old thread does not finish in time, a new task will still be added to the pool.

Comment: The answer to the question above "do this also apply for newScheduledThreadPool(1) or not?" is YES. The `1` passed to the constructor of the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` is `corePoolSize`. Unless you set it to `0`, which is not recommended, the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` will re-create the threads if the previously executing thread died from an exception and one is need. The **only** difference between `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` and `newScheduledThreadPool(1)` is that in the first case the executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads.

Comment: The difference is the DelegatedScheduledExecutorService exposes only `schedule` and `invoke` related methods. All other configuration methods can not 
 be invoked from it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by wings and tagir the differences is in "how to manage failure".

About Thread your thread is in Wait status; `park` is not a status but is a method to put the Thread in wait status; see also

[How to detect thread being blocked by IO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891386/how-to-detect-thread-being-blocked-by-io)

However, let me suggest a different way to implement a scheduled thread on Java EE; you should take a look at EJB's [TimerService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)

```
@Singleton
public class TimerSessionBean {
    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;   

    public void setTimer(long intervalDuration) {
        Timer timer = timerService.createTimer(intervalDuration, 
                "Created new programmatic timer");
    }

    @Timeout
    public void lookForData(Timer timer) {
        //this.setLastProgrammaticTimeout(new Date());
        ....
    }

    //OR
    @Schedule(minute = "*/1", hour = "*")
    public void runEveryMinute() {
      ...
    }

   }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll also check TimerService EJB.